# Finding out-group in unrooted tree

Tags: r, phylogenetics

Im trying to find the out-group in the alignment my data files [file a](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N60Va-smHbsmCePOnkVL_jjAaxCagZWf/view?usp=sharing) and  [file b](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_E0Ozgv_7Wtxr9AKPrvW606IWH99hIPb/view?usp=sharing) both the case i'm getting NA when i run this     `pars.a$tip.label[pars.a$edge[which.max(pars.a$edge.length),2]]`

I tried NJ instead of upgma i do still get NA not sure what is the issue ,but at the same time when i used other alignment file [with 50 sequence](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10P6qF3nrXlnm-tUONK5bTAPqR4wapX-q/view?usp=sharing)  works fine.

```
a<-read.alignment("abhi_seq/final_abhi_tempa1.fas", format="fasta")
a.phydat<-as.phyDat(a)
dist.a.phydat<-dist.dna(as.DNAbin(a.phydat))
upgma.a<-upgma(dist.a.phydat)
parsimony(upgma.a,a.phydat)
pars.a <- optim.parsimony(upgma.a, a.phydat)
pars.a<-acctran(pars.a, a.phydat)
pars.a$tip.label[pars.a$edge[which.max(pars.a$edge.length),2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fact is that the present upgma tree as a midpoint rooting here, corresponding to node 46.

```
getRoot(upgma.a)
```

so for this kind of tree, I recommend you to use the midpoint() rooting function.

```
pars.a <- optim.parsimony(upgma.a, a.phydat)
pars.a<-acctran(pars.a, a.phydat)
plot(midpoint(pars.a))
```

Comment: let me try it out and how do we decide which rooting to use? based on observation after plotting

Comment: yes visual inspection seems relevant. It totally depends of your input data, whether your sequences are strongly conserved (without evident outgroup) or more divergent. I think you may write a control loop after constructing the upgma tree, by checking if the ouptput of `getRoot(upgma.a)` returns a node or a tip. If it is a node, then it might proceed with the `midpoint()` version.

Comment: I haven't tried with ML but this mid point should work with ML as well?

Comment: yes, probably! it is probably a more universal solution, but not the necessarily the best one!

Comment: last time i was looking to compare tress which you had suggested turn them into dedrogram and then for comparison you suggested something this '
pars.a.rooted<-root(pars.a, outgroup="ABN10911", resolve.root=T)
pars.a.rooted.dd<-as.dendrogram(force.ultrametric(pars.a.rooted))' how to do the same  here shall i put node 46 as the outgroup?

Comment: It won't work because you have only 45 tip labels, if I remember well. I think you may run: `pars.a.rooted.dd<-as.dendrogram(force.ultrametric(midpoint(pars.a)))`

Comment: works perfectly fine for parsimony and...for pars for ML i m doing this rectify me if im wrong "ml.a.rooted.dd<-as.dendrogram(force.ultrametric(midpoint(fit$tree)))
"

Comment: seems ok. It is true that in the previous code, we used  `root(midpoint(fit$tree), outgroup="AAA64460", resolve.root=T)` to force using a given tip as root. Using `force.ultrametric(midpoint(pars.a))` should work too indeed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109380/discussion-between-krushnach-chandra-and-thomas-duge-de-bernonville).